# como faço para redirecionar uma pagina clicando em um option de um select pelo google chrome?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mobile, bootstrap

estou utilizando esse jquery já tentei usar o change também porém não executa

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select-native-fc").on('click', function(){
            if($("#select-native-fc").val() == "ASM2")
            {
                alert('Teste');
            }
});
</script>
```

**Código do select:**

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">  
    <label for="select-native-fc">Linhas de Assembly:</label>
    <select name="select-native-fc" id="select-native-fc" class="assy">
        <option value="http://www.youtube.com">Assembly 1</option>
        <option value="ASM2">Assembly 2</option>        
        <option value="ASM3">Assembly 3</option>
        <option value="ASM4">Assembly 4</option>
        <option value="ASM5">Assembly 5</option>
        <option value="ASM6">Assembly 6</option>
        <option value="ASM7">Assembly 7</option>
        <option value="ASM8">Assembly 8</option>
        <option value="ASM9">Assembly 9</option>
        <option value="ASM10">Assembly 10</option>
        <option value="ASMX">Assembly X</option>
        <option value="ASMY">Assembly Y</option>
        <option value="ASMZ">Assembly Z</option>

    </select>
</div>
```

Precisava que ao clicar em algum *option* redireciona para uma outra página estou utilizando jquery para mobile os eventos só funciona para o IE porém no google chrome não funciona e nem para a plataforma mobile estou utilizando essas bibliotecas do jquery abaixo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: A ação deve ser feita no `onChange` e não no `onClick`

Comment: Testa `.on('change',`, como o @rray sugeriu.

Comment: ja tentei não deu certo

Comment: Não deu certo quer dizer o que? não exibiu o alert?

Comment: sim não executa nada ja tentei fazer até direto no select o onChange="alert('teste');"

Comment: Vc tentou usar `.assy` ao invés de `#select-native-fc` para debug?

Comment: tentei também e não deu certo o mais próximo que consegui em jquery foi com onclick só que ele executa o alert no select direto nem chega abrir a caixa de seleção

Comment: Então use `<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   

$("#select-native-fc").change(function(){
    var val = $("#select-native-fc").val();
    alert(val);
    //your code
});
});

</script>` vai funcionar.

Comment: nada ainda deve ser alguma coisa na biblioteca

Comment: Dependendo da biblioteca vc deverá usar o `.live` invés de `.change` ou `.on`

Comment: Fiz um fiddle aqui. https://jsfiddle.net/oeo267j4/

Comment: você não esqueceu de fechar o $(document) não?? pelo que vi faltou um "});" dai o código verifica erro e não executa

Answer (score 3):

Problema era que o ready não estava fechado, código corrigido:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select-native-fc").on('click', function(){
            if($("#select-native-fc").val() == "ASM2")
            {
                alert('Teste');
            }
    });
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Hum.. Código quase certo é faltou fechar }) e use prevenir `$("#select-native-fc").trigger("click");`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select-native-fc").on('click', function(){
      if($("#select-native-fc").val() == "ASM2") {
        alert('Teste');
      }
    });
    $("#select-native-fc").trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-field-contain">  
    <label for="select-native-fc">Linhas de Assembly:</label>
    <select name="select-native-fc" id="select-native-fc" class="assy">
        <option value="http://www.youtube.com">Assembly 1</option>
        <option value="ASM2">Assembly 2</option>        
        <option value="ASM3">Assembly 3</option>
        <option value="ASM4">Assembly 4</option>
        <option value="ASM5">Assembly 5</option>
        <option value="ASM6">Assembly 6</option>
        <option value="ASM7">Assembly 7</option>
        <option value="ASM8">Assembly 8</option>
        <option value="ASM9">Assembly 9</option>
        <option value="ASM10">Assembly 10</option>
        <option value="ASMX">Assembly X</option>
        <option value="ASMY">Assembly Y</option>
        <option value="ASMZ">Assembly Z</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Aqui rodou bonito e alguém não rodou, posso modificar diferente mais código especifico de haddle.